# What is the reason for the color scheming of Nolan's Batman franchise?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises, christopher-nolan, batman-begins, the-dark-knight

Throughout the three Batman films, there has been one running theme in common.  Each movie *has its own color scheme*.

- **Batman Begins** - Brown & Black
- **The Dark Knight** - Blue & Red
- **Dark Knight Rises** - White & Black

[image]

What is Nolan's reason for this?  Is there a meaning behind the colors that directly link back into the major theme of the films?  Or are these colors a way to represent the overall situation throughout the movie?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I see these colors/movie titles as the day in the life of a bat, beginning at sunset (orange) and ending at sunrise (white/bight) with a dark night in between (blue). Also plays on the titles; BEGINS, NIGHT and sunRISE. That is another nice conclusion to the saga.

Comment: That is an impresive explanation

Comment: The question asks for _Nolan's_ reason for the colours.  Is there any evidence the director _intended_ the colour schemes — and names — for this reason?  Or is it merely an after-the-fact (though very interesting and imaginative!) rationalisation?

Answer (score 7):

Not knowing much about the upcoming movie, nor anything about Bane the main adversary, I can only comment on the first two.

The choice of brown evokes grime and dirt and brooding menance - a perfect analogy of the scene in Gotham, particularly with The Narrows - a slum part of the city, a no-go area for police similar to the (no-longer existing) Kowloon in Hong Kong.  The main adversary is Scarecrow, and the brown and black theme also evokes earthiness.

The brighter blue/red theme in The Dark Knight is perfect for the character of the Joker.  The burning Batman symbol evokes a smiling Joker mouth, and ties into a key line of Alfreds:

> Well, because he thought it was good sport. Because some men aren't looking for anything logical, like money. They can't be bought, bullied, reasoned, or negotiated with. Some men just want to watch the world burn

Answer (score 5):

I recently stumbled upon an article explaining the same

> Batman Begins had a dominatly brown color scheme to paint Gotham City
>   as the crime infested wasteland shithole that it was. The Dark
>   Knight's color scheme was mostly blue,which was done to create a
>   contrast...at first it is used to create a vibe of calm relaxation in
>   showing that Batman has really made a difference and gotten the city
>   out of the slump it was in in Batman Begins...but then when the shit
>   starts to go down,the blue turns out to be a corrupted false sense of
>   security and is then used as a means of shaping the dark and bleak
>   atmosphere that will carry over the remander of the film

[This post on a forum is a good read itself.](http://kefchat.proboards.com/index.cgi?board=general&action=display&thread=217)

Comment: I wouldn't really call it an article, more like a forum rant.

Comment: @TylerShads But though it's an individual opinion (and I don't know the quality of the rest of the "article"), it certainly offers some interresting viewpoints on the question's topic.

Comment: @ChristianRau I will agree to that.

Comment: @TylerShads: I find it more of a insightful & thoughtful rant.

Comment: @karthik Finally finishing all of it I agree.  I see article and expect a blog or the like, when I get taken to see a forum post, my innate cynicism sets in :)